# Trouble Udating UI from a Seperate Thread

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

I've been messing around with the answer given here
[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

I'm getting the error Method 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' Text not found from the following code

```
Private Delegate Sub setControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(control As Control, propertyName As String, propertyValue As Object)

Public Sub setControlPropertyThreadSafe(control As Control, propertyName As String, propertyValue As Object)
    If control.InvokeRequired = True Then
        control.Invoke(New setControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(AddressOf setControlPropertyThreadSafe), New Object() {control, propertyName, propertyValue})
    Else
        control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, control, New Object() {control, propertyName, propertyValue}) 'This is where the error occurs
    End If
End Sub
```

From a separate thread I calling this method with the following line

```
UI.setControlPropertyThreadSafe(UI.lblExcel, "Text", "Inserting Data into YTD Template")
```

Any help regarding this error will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, _
    Nothing, control, New Object() {control, propertyName, propertyValue})
```

Should be

```
control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, _
    Nothing, control, New Object() {propertyValue})
```

The last parameter to `InvokeMember` is the parameter list for the method, which for a property setting is just the value you wish to set.  The question you linked to has it correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I'll check it when i get into work tomorrow.